# Which IP is picked up when using Remote Desktop?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop

This is not a coding question but I can't find a clear answer anywhere so I thought the online community will know. Let's say, I'm currently using computer A and running Remote Desktop on Windows to access computer B. From computer B, I sign in to a website. Would the admin for that website be able to tell I was on computer A when I signed in? Or can they only pick up my computer B IP address? I don't know much about networking and remote desktop so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Admin would see the IP form computer B. All Remote Desktop (RDP) allows you to do is connect to another computer and control it, as Microsoft puts it

> With Remote Desktop Connection, you can connect to a computer running Windows from another computer running Windows that's connected to the same network or to the Internet. For example, you can use all of your work computer's programs, files, and network resources from your home computer, and it's just like you're sitting in front of your computer at work.

So when your remote to another machine and launch a web browser it is still running on that remote machine and all the requests are sent only from that remote machine and any site wanting to inspect incoming data will only see that it is coming from Machine B.